Отслеживание цвета пикселя по координатам, если он сходится, то включается функция
Я только начинаю изучать Python, и пытаюсь написать что-то вроде кликера.
По идеи программа должна открывать интерфейс нажатием клавиши "Х", смотреть на определенные координаты и проверять цвет(условно зеленый), если цвет(зеленый), то включается функция с кликом по координатам и программа функционирует дальше, если цвет не совпадает(условно красный), то программа начинает всю функцию по новой, пока не появится нужный цвет(зеленый).
Не могу понять, как это сделать.
На данный момент я использовал три библиотеки: pyautogui, mss и numpy.
Буду благодарен каждому варианту! Спасибо!

Для начала, приложите ваш код, тогда можно будет понять в чём ваша ошибка. Но вообще у вас максимально странный набор библиотек под вашу задачу. Посмотрите в сторону tkinter, PyQt, pygame, например

Сконцентрируйтесь на каждой проблеме по отдельности. Например попробуйте сперва определить RGB пикселя по конкретным координатам. Потом решайте следующею проблему.. и т.д.
